# Javascript encoding i18n JSON Accent issue

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I have an encoding issue with i18n Library. Actually, I can't use accent in my JSON file because it's not well encoded.
I've tried

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
    cache: false
});
```

and also added

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

in my header and it still doesn't work.
Any idea? What it could be?

Here is the link of the sample page :

```
http://m0si.com/lang/index.html?setLng=fr-FR
```

Answer (score 1):

The json file in http://m0si.com/lang/locales/fr-FR/ns.special.json is not encoded properly.
Try to force headers to utf-8 there.

PS: You have the $.ajaxSetup command twice on your page.

Comment: You mean in the JSON file? How do you do that?

Comment: Webserver Configuration. However i noticed that you have $.ajaxSetup comand twice on your page, once for utf8 and once for iso88591