# How to use i18next? Problems with translations

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, internationalization, i18next

I want to use a internationalization option at my jQuery Mobile and jQuery webside. I tried to generate an example with the documentation on http://i18next.com but it seems I failed. Does anybody has experiences with i18next?

Here my example:

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/i18next-1.5.6.min.js"                 type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/translation.js"                       type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="content">
      <div id="headline1" data-i18n="headline"></div>
        <table width="100%" border="0" id="menu1" class="menu">
          <tr id="surname">
            <td width="50%" data-i18n="menu.surname"></td>
            <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="firstName">
            <td width="50%" data-i18n="menu.firstName"></td>
            <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Translation files:
/locales/de/translation.json

```
{
  "menu": {
    "surname": "Name:",
    "firstName": "Vorname:"
  },

  "headline": "Daten:",
  "headline_1": "Daten Allgemein:",
  "headline_2": "Daten Speziell:"
}
```

/locales/en/translation.json

/locales/dev/translation.json

```
{
  "menu": {
    "surname": "Name:",
    "firstName": "First Name:"
  },

  "headline": "Data:",
  "headline_1": "Daten Common:",
  "headline_2": "Daten Specific:"
}
```

/js/translation.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  language_complete = navigator.language.split("-");
  language = (language_complete[0]);
  console.log("Sprache (root): %s", language);

  i18n.init({ lng: language });
  i18n.init({ debug: true });
  $(".menu").i18n();
  $("headline").i18n();
});
```

The translation for the menu I get is "menu.name" instead of expected "Name:".
For the headline I get no translation but I expected "Data:" or "Daten:".

If i try the following direct call I get no translation: 
    i18n.t("menu.surname", { defaultValue: "Name:"});

Does anybody know what the problem is? Or does anybody has a working example that fits what I try to do?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Main problem is you can't call `i18n.t("menu.surname", { defaultValue: "Name:"});` directly after initialization, as loading the resources from server is async, so basically you try to translate before i18next fetched the resources.

Instead load it with callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  language_complete = navigator.language.split("-");
  language = (language_complete[0]);
  console.log("Sprache (root): %s", language);

  i18n.init({ lng: language, debug: true }, function() {
      // save to use translation function as resources are fetched
      $(".menu").i18n();
      $("headline").i18n();
  });
});
```

or use flag to load resources synchron.

By the way:
Your html code has one closing `</div>` too many.

The call to `$("headline").i18n();` should be `$("#headline").i18n();`.

Comment: If this solved your issue you could mark this as answered. So the question get closed.

Comment: One more question: If I have a translation text with a mutated vowel (umlaut) than I get just a "�". If I use the HTML notation (e.g. "&auml;") I see the HTML notation and not the mutated vowel. What I am doing wrong? Thank you for helping.

Comment: assert encoding on page and in json is utf8. <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: No changes, I have still the "�" character.

Comment: Example:
- Expected text: Fläche
- Real text: Fl�che (if Fläche is the JSON text) or
             Fl&auml;che (if Fl&auml;che is the JSON text)

I did only changed the HTML mata tag on index.html. How can I set the charset for JSON? Do I need also changes there? Currently my JSON file looks like described above.

Comment: It's more a server setting: you might take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363394/javascript-encoding-i18n-json-accent-issue (just get the json down to the client in utf-8 - not sure how to configurate your server)

Comment: I have no server, so maybe I need another internationalization possibility. Thank you for your help.

Comment: it's not the tool. if you're serving the stuff from filesystem you might have stored the json files in some iso format instead of utf8.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Basic Sample Usage</title>

        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
        <script src="js/i18next.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    </head>

    <body>

        <h3> you can switch lng via ?setLng='lngTag' </h3>
        <a id="en" href="?setLng=en"> en </a>
            | &nbsp;
        <a id="de" href="?setLng=de"> de </a>  

        <h3>loaded via attribute 'data-i18n' and $('.nav').i18n();</h3>

        <h5>basic text</h5>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" id = "navy" data-i18n="nav.home"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.1"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.2"></a></li>
        </ul>

        <button id="btn" data-i18n="ns.common:add"></button>

        <h5>extended usage of 'data-i18n' - apply to other attributes</h5>
        <div id="extendedAttr">
            <input data-i18n="[placeholder]ns.common:attr.placeholder;" type="text"></input>
            <button data-i18n="[title]ns.common:attr.title;btn.hoverMe;"></button>
        </div>

        <script>

        $.i18n.init({
            //lng: 'en',
            ns: { namespaces: ['ns.common', 'ns.special'], defaultNs: 'ns.special'},
            useLocalStorage: false,
            debug: true
        }, function(t) {

            //$('#navy').i18n(); for single 
            $('.nav').i18n();  // for group
            $('#btn').i18n();
            $('#extendedAttr').i18n();
        });



        </script>

    </body>

    </html>


locales/en/ns.special.json <=> make same for de/ns.speacial.json
{
    "nav": {
        "home": "en home",
        "1": "en  link 1",
        "2": " en link 2"
    }, 
    "btn": {
        "hoverMe": "en hover me!"
    }
}

and locales/de/ns.common.json <=> make same for en/ns.speacial.json
{
    "app": {
        "company": {
          "name": "my company"
        }
    },
    "attr": {
        "placeholder": "de translated placeholder",
        "title": "translated title" 
    },
    "add": "de add"
}
```

Comment: For i18n with backbone.js implementation refer the below link with require.js https://github.com/manishcm/i18n-backbone