# How to translate html page using the plugin i18next?

Tags: i18next

i see example page [How to use i18next? Problems with translations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005791/how-to-use-i18next-problems-with-translations)

but after this code, i have in console error: Uncaught ReferenceError: i18n is not defined

WHY??? Where can I download i18next.js to convert html page?

Answer (score 1):

[From the official site](http://%60http://i18next.com/docs/%60):
there are two possibilities: to install it with `npm` from [repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18next), or

`https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/master/i18next.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.x of the library, `i18n` has been replaced by `i18next` and the API has changed considerably.